# How do I play multiple SpeechSynthesizer Streams in the bbackground?

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player, text-to-speech

I've tried using something along the lines of:

```
public async Task ReadParagraph(int id)
{
    var mp = (App.Current as App).mediaPlayer;
    var ns = (App.Current as App).nextStream;
    readerPosition = id;
    var tb = Items.OfType<TextBlock>();
    if (readerPosition < tb.Count())
    {
        if (synth == null)
            synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.DefaultVoice;
        var str = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(tb.ElementAt(readerPosition).Text);
        var ms = MediaSource.CreateFromStream(str, str.ContentType);
        mp.Source = ms;
        mp.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = 1.3;
        mp.Play();
    }
}
```

And in the `App.xml.cs` file:

```
private async void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
        await currentStory.Commands.ReadParagraph(Reader.Current.readerPosition + 1);
}
```

In theory this works. The problem is, there's 3s+ pause between each synth streams. On WP8.1, with `MediaElement` it worked perfectly, but it seems like MediaPlayer, with its `Background Audio Playback` capability seems to be working on different terms.

Also, is there any other way to change `MediaPlayer`'s default playback rate instead of changing ebvery file's separately? It doesn't seem to work 100% of the time the way I have it set up currently.

I've also been thinking about initializing the entire text as a `List<SpeechSynthesisStream>`, but this seems like it would take up a lot of memory with long texts.

What'd the best option to handle this?

Comment: Did you use the out-process-background-audio, or the new in-process one? Is that possible to share your demo
?

Comment: I've used [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio) tutorial though I'm not using that `isBackground` variable anywhere right now. I also followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer) but I'm not using the `MediaPlayerElement`.